# Java thread local class

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model

Is there a way to tell JVM that the class is used exclusively from the single thread => JVM is allowed to optimize operations with fields (loads/stores) cross syncronization actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's the default mode of operation. That's why you need to take extra steps (such as `volatile`  or `synchronized`) when **not** running with a single thread.

Comment: Of cause I know that this is default, but maybe there is a hack to tell JVM, "I KNOW this is unsafe, but please, optimize fields ops within this class regardless synchronization"?

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: a class performs synchronization to access some resources from another class, while *itself* it is strictly thread-local (obtained from `ThreadLocal` and `ownerThread == Thread.currentThread()` check is performed on each operation). So what I have: 1) many field loads 2) synchronization on external resource 3) many field loads. I don't want JVM to repeat loads without actual need.

Comment: Well, you're out of luck. Is it a performance hotspot, or are you doing premature optimization?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell JVM that the class is used exclusively from the single thread

You can't explicitly tell it that, but under limited circumstances the hotspot JVM can infer that objects cannot possibly be seen by other threads and performs optimizations such as object decomposition/stack allocation and lock elision.

The feature is called [escape analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis).

Comment: The object is leaking by defenition, to ThreadLocalMap. The object is too big, methods are big and abstractions are too deep, so I don't risk to allocate it, hoping jit will perform EA.

Comment: Then you either have to redesign your code to not let it escape or you will have to look for other ways to optimize performance.